# Looping through database

Tags: php, loops, mysqli

I would like to loop through my players table and for each player run the following code, Can I use the following or is using "else" the wrong option, I would need it to run through all the if statements to see if there is a match, then update the database as required. Basically what I need to know is am I on the right track, or should I be looking at using do, while, foreach, else, elseif, switch etc. the code below is just and example. Just trying to understand the theory.

```
<?php
$getresult = $conn->query('SELECT id FROM users');
 while ($getrow = mysqli_fetch_array($getresult); {
    $player = $getrow['id'];

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM scores WHERE player_id='$playerId' ORDER by points ASC");
$row = $result->fetch_array();
$row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($row_count...) {


}else{

    if ($row_count...) {

    }else{

         if () {

         }else{
  }
//SQL update statement would go here..
}
```

Comment: Looks like a _Do it for me_ question. VTC

Comment: A bit of sensible code indentation would go a long way towards understanding the code as well. And more importantly debugging the obvious errors in it

Comment: So, we want the sum of either the bottom 5, or bottom 10 lowest scores depending on whether there's fewer or more than 20 rows.  Or, we do nothing if fewer than 10 scores.  Is that right ?

Comment: RiggsFolly - No a do it for me question at all more of a is do what I should be using or am I looking at this all wrong, sorry for the code display, still trying to figure out the forum. 2-cents tim, you are are sort of correct. Basically I would like to loop through my users table, and for each user it finds, to apply the if statements accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like `SELECT id FROM playersTable` then in the `while` loop fetch the player_id and then move the rest of your code inside that loop. Is that what you are looking for or am I missing something?

```
// $player = $_SESSION['id'];
$playersResult = $conn->query('SELECT id FROM playersTable');
while ($playersRow = mysqli_fetch_array($playersResult); {
    $playerId = $playersRow['id'];

    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM scores WHERE player_id='$playerId' ORDER by points ASC");
    $row = $result->fetch_array();
    $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($row_count >= 20) { // checks that at least 10 rows available
        $result = $conn->query("SELECT points FROM scores WHERE player_id='$playerId' ORDER by points ASC LIMIT 10"); // select 10 lowest points
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $total = array($row['points']);
            $sum = array_sum($total);
            echo $sum;
        }
    }
    else if ($row_count>=10) { // checks that at least 10 rows available
        $result = $conn->query("SELECT points FROM scores WHERE player_id='$playerId' ORDER by points ASC LIMIT 5"); // select 5 lowest points
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $total = array($row['points']);
            $sum = array_sum($total);
            echo $sum;
        } 
    }

    //SQL update statement would go here..
}
```

You also might want to check your sum logic, without seeing your table structure I don't think the array_sum is going to do what you want. You can use the `SQL SUM()` to do the calculation for you.

Comment: More of a comment than an answer! Beware the downvote

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I just started contributing. Is there a reference for that kind of stuff?

Comment: Thanks, not to worried about the sum as I have received help with that and have updated accordingly, that is working fine now. So basically I can use the while statement to loop through the users table, this will then apply each user id found to the if statements within it?